# Лишний объект при инициализации через конструктор

Tags: java, конструктор, инициализация

Коллеги, будьте любезны, помогите новичку разобраться. У меня есть классWindow содержащий конструктор

```
public class Window {
    Window(int marker){
        System.out.println("Window #:"+marker);
    }
}
```

Есть класс House. В этом классе также содержится конструктор, но есть так же объект класса Window и метод

```
public class House {
   Window window1=new Window(1);
    public House(){
        System.out.println("HOUSE");
        Window window2=new Window(2);

    }
    public void f(){
        System.out.println("METHOD");
    }
}
```

Почему, когда я с помощью конструктора инициализирую объект класса House, кроме этого объекта я получаю еще и объект window1?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        House house=new House();

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моей голове это выглядит примерно так:
Я создаю объект класса House, содержащий объект класса Window window2, с помощью конструктора. Объект window1 лежит за пределами этого конструктора. Почему он объявляется если его затрагивали только в классе Window?

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос.... почему инициализируется объект window1?

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Порядок инициализации полей и блоков при наследовании

Есть суперкласс А, от данного суперкласса наследуется подкласс B:

```
public class A {
      
    {
        System.out.println("A class. No static block 1");
    }
  
    {
        System.out.println("A class. No static block 2");
    }
  
    {
        System.out.println("A class. No static block 3");
    }
  
    static {
        System.out.println("A class. Static block 1");
  
    }
  
    static {
        System.out.println("A class. Static block 2");
  
    }
    public static String a1 = psv("a1");
      
    public String a11 = pnsv("a11");
  
    static {
        System.out.println("A class. Static block 3");
  
    }
    public static String a2 = psv("a2");
  
    private static String psv(String a) {
        System.out.println("A class. Static perem " + a);
        return a;
  
    }
  
    private String pnsv(String a) {
        System.out.println("A class. No static perem " + a);
        return a;
  
    }
      
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A class. Constructor");
    }
  
  
    public String a22 = pnsv("a22");
  
    public static String a3 = psv("a3");
      
    {
        System.out.println("A class. No static block 4");
    }
      
    public String a33 = pnsv("a33");
  
}
```

И класс B, который наследуется от класса A:

```
public class B extends A{
    private int b = bb(20);
 
    public B(int b) {   
        this.b = b;
    }
     
    private int bb(int x) {
        System.out.println("B class. No static perem " + x);
        return 0;
    }
 
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B class. Constructor");
    }
     
    static {
        System.out.println("B class. Static block 1");
    }
     
     
}
```

Вызов конструктора у класса B:

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
     
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
A class. Static block 1
A class. Static block 2
A class. Static perem a1
A class. Static block 3
A class. Static perem a2
A class. Static perem a3
B class. Static block 1
A class. No static block 1
A class. No static block 2
A class. No static block 3
A class. No static perem a11
A class. No static perem a22
A class. No static block 4
A class. No static perem a33
A class. Constructor
B class. No static perem 20
B class. Constructor
```

Т.е. порядок такой:

1. Статические блоки и статические поля в порядке объявления
   суперкласса(А)
2. Статические блоки и статические поля в порядке объявления подкласса(В)
3. Не статические блоки и не статические поля в порядке объявления суперкласса(А)
4. Конструктор суперкласса(А)
5. Не статические блоки и не статические поля в порядке объявления подкласса(B)
6. Конструктор подкласса(B)

В данном случае смотреть от 1 до 4, т.к. подклассов здесь нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class House {
   Window window1=new Window(1);
    public House(){
        System.out.println("HOUSE");
        Window window2=new Window(2);
    }
}
```

При создании дома создается window2 (в конструкторе)
и window1 в поле класса

конструктор создает экземпляр класса и если твой код подразумевает инициализацию других объектов, например в полях класса, в твоем случае - ( Window window1=new Window(1);), то этот код тоже выполнится